# MapReduce Program Command Error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a simple mapreduce program and am now trying to run it. Someone gave me this command to run:

`hadoop jar <out jar> <main class> <arg1> <arg2>`

My jar is called IntCount.jar and the program file is called IntCount.java. There is also a file in my directory called IntCount.class. However, when I tried

`hadoop jar IntCount.jar IntCount input output`

I got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IntCount`

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure IntCount.class inside of IntCount.jar and it doesn't contain inside of any package except the default package?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I check if IntCount.class is inside of IntCount.jar?

Comment: Use a Archive Manager like WinZip or 7Zip

Comment: I opened IntCount.jar in a decompiler and it doesn't look like IntCount.class is in it. What should I do now?